# How can I resolve zlib-enum, zlib-binding, zlib-conduit conflict when installing Yesod

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I am trying to install my Yesod web app on another machine.

I have it installed fine on my current machine and can `cabal install` it on there without any problems.

I seem to run into trouble with it on the other machine though (which is a fresh Ubuntu VM - e.g., no cabal packages where installed on it prior.

Note that I changed nothing about my setup (e.g. cabal files are exactly the same).

This is the error I keep getting:

> cabal: cannot configure zlib-enum-0.2.2. It requires zlib-bindings ==0.1.*
>   For the dependency on zlib-bindings ==0.1.* there are these packages:
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0 and zlib-bindings-0.1.0.1. However none of them are available.
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0 was excluded because zlib-conduit-0.2.0.1 requires zlib-bindings >=0.0.3 && <0.1
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0 was excluded because zlib-bindings-0.0.3.2 was selected instead
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency zlib-bindings ==0.0.3.2
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0.1 was excluded because zlib-conduit-0.2.0.1 requires zlib-bindings >=0.0.3 && <0.1
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0.1 was excluded because zlib-bindings-0.0.3.2 was selected instead
>   zlib-bindings-0.1.0.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency zlib-bindings ==0.0.3.2

I have tried all kind of ways to resolve this, but keep running into this same problem, no matter what path I take.

My guess is, that theses packages' versions are conflicting at this point.

How can I resolve this until it gets fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prime example of cabal dependency hell. Theoretically, the fault lies with `zlib-enum`, since it should have had a major version bump to reflect the major version bump with `zlib-bindings`. But really, the problem is cabal's dependency analyzer. The new one will hopefully be ready soon.

In the meanwhile, depending on zlib-enum <= 0.2.1 should work.

Also, @ehird's answer should be helpful too, though it may not entirely solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution when I get a chance. Any word on when the new dependency analyzer will be available?

Comment: @ThorstenLorenz: I've expanded my answer with some information (originally as a comment, but I had more to add and it was getting long).

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I just was able to rebuild and run `yesod devel` after updating my cabal file according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try installing the new [Yesod Platform](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/03/announcing-yesod-platform) ([Hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-platform)):

```
cabal install yesod-platform
```

It's a metapackage that depends on specific versions of Yesod and all its dependencies, designed to avoid versioning conflicts like this.

You could also try the in-development version of cabal-install, which has the modular dependency solver Michael mentioned. If you `darcs get --lazy http://darcs.haskell.org/cabal/`, you should be able to run `bootstrap.sh` in `cabal/cabal-install` to install it (but you should probably wipe `~/.cabal` and `~/.ghc` first).<sup>1</sup> You still have to explicitly request the modular solver by passing `--solver=modular` to `cabal`, though.

Note that, even though it's a development version, it's actually pretty stable; lots of people on GHC 7.4.1 (including me) use it, since the version on Hackage doesn't compile. I haven't had any issues so far.

<sup>1</sup> This is for Linux; I think the relevant directory is `~/Library/Haskell` on OS X. I have no idea what to do on Windows, especially since the shell script won't run there.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the details. I'm sure together with Micheal's suggestion I should be able to figure this out now.